# Parse nested json failed flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have this json response that contains servicetype,vehiclemodels,accessories,working status as array but i cannot access any of the class,when i print `print(obj);` it just shows null

**Json file**

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "",
  "data": {
    "service_types": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Car Wash"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Full Body Wash"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Polishing"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Engine Oil Checkup"
      },
     
    ],
    "vehicle_models": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "SUV"
      }
    ],
    "accessories": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Mat Cover"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Cash"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Engine Room washing"
      }
    ],
    "working_statuses": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Registered"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Work started"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Work completed"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Cancelled"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Code for extracting data

```
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(Urls.DasboardData),
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    body: json.encode({
      "vehicle_models": "",
      "service_types": "",
      "station_id":Station_id,
      "accessories": "",
      "working_statuses": "",
    }));

Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(response.body);

var data = value['data'];
if (data.length > 0) {
  
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
     print(obj);
    var service_type_obj = obj['service_types'];
    var vehicle_models_obj = obj['vehicle_models'];
    var accessories_obj = obj['accessories'];
    var working_statuses_obj = obj['working_statuses'];
    DataList.add(GetAllModel(
      service_type_obj['id'],
      service_type_obj['name'],
      vehicle_models_obj['id'],
      vehicle_models_obj['name'],
      accessories_obj['id'],
      accessories_obj['name'],
      working_statuses_obj['id'],
      working_statuses_obj['name'],
    ));
  }

  setState(() {
    print("UI UPDATED");
  });
}
else
  {

  }
```

Model

```
class GetAllModel {
  String service_type_id,
        service_type_name,
        vehicle_models_id,
        vehicle_models_name,
        accessories_id,
        accessories_name,
        working_statuses_id,
       working_statuses_name;


  GetAllModel(
      this.service_type_id,
      this.service_type_name,
      this.vehicle_models_id,
      this.vehicle_models_name,
      this.accessories_id,
      this.accessories_name,
      this.working_statuses_id,
      this.working_statuses_name,
      );
}
```

Comment: When you print the variable before entering the if conditional, what does it show?

Comment: i can print the length and respose of `data` ,but when it enter to for loop it shows null @FelipeVergara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at the time of iterating your information, the data size is 4, but this It contains 4 objects, therefore you will not be able to access data[i] because data[i] does not exist, if it exists data ['service_types'] which is a list and here if you could iterate the information that this contains object.

So to be able to access the information of your objects you must iterate them like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data['service_types'].length; i++) {
   print(data['service_types'][i]);
}
```

and the same for the other objects.

An alternative to iterate:

```
for (var item in data.values) {
   print(item);
}
```

Comment: so i have to do this all the 4 object,is there any better way@Felipe Vergara

Comment: In this way you can iterate all the info, it prints the information of each object.

for (var item in data.values) {
      print(item);
    }

Comment: can you show some code example @Felipe Vergara

Comment: how can i access the data then send to model,how do i do that @Felipe Vergara

Comment: Your model is not understood, with the information you are receiving today, some fields will be null, is that the behavior you expect?

Comment: all thing in common is name and id in each objects and i tried to pass the extracted data to model so i can use the model items name in the list or listview @Felipe Vergara

Answer (score 0):

You need to change these:

```
var service_type_obj = obj['service_types'];
var vehicle_models_obj = obj['vehicle_models'];
var accessories_obj = obj['accessories'];
var working_statuses_obj = obj['working_statuses'];
```

into this:

```
var service_type_obj = obj['service_types'][0];
var vehicle_models_obj = obj['vehicle_models'][0];
var accessories_obj = obj['accessories'][0];
var working_statuses_obj = obj['working_statuses'][0];
```

You're objects are located inside a list, to access them, you have to use an index, like[0].

Comment: i tried that  also when i `print(obj)` it shows null it stops at `var service_type_obj = obj['service_types'];` even if i add `var service_type_obj = obj['service_types'][0];` it still stuck @Huthaifa Muayyad